# What is the equivalent of re-formatting and checking syntax on save of Textmate in SublimeText2?

Tags: textmate, sublimetext2

I recently switched to SublimeText2 from Textmate and I've been enjoying it.
But there are some features of Textmate which I don't know for SBT2.

1. Selecting a block of code and pressing `CMD+OPTION+[` re-formats the selected block.
2. While saving a file `CMD+S`, ruby or jquery or coffee-script, etc.. Texmate checks the syntax of the code.

How to do the same with SBT2?

Comment: I'm not very proficient with Sublime, but the last time I looked at it (before plugins were introduced) there was no way of reformat.

Comment: Those are the two features that I miss in Sublime. May be someone will figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check syntax on save you can use [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeLinter) and to reformat code you can use something like the following depending on what languages you work with:

- [HTMLTidy](https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimeHtmlTidy)
- [Sublime-HTMLPrettify](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify) (HTML, JS, CSS)
- [Pretty JSON](https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson)
- [PHPTidy](https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimePhpTidy)
- [PythonTidy](https://github.com/witsch/SublimePythonTidy)
- [BeautifyRuby](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby)

There are plenty of other similar and other useful extensions and plugins here: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community

All of which can be easily installed and kept up to date using [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).